# How do I keep a div with slideDown() with a mouseLeave() trigger for the slideUp() from firing if I mouseLeave() to another specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is create a dropdown that slides down when a link is clicked and depending on which link is clicked a specific hidden div is shown. I want it to switch between the hidden divs gracefully in the exposed dropdown when another link is clicked. We've pretty much got the first part of that figured out. What I'm tryiing to figure out is how to make the dropdown slide back up after a delay when the mouse leaves the dropdown and the menu,so it stays open if your still mouseon the menu or the dropdown, not just the dropdown or the menu. What I've got below almost works. The only thing missing how to keep the dropdown open when moving back to the menu.  Any suggestions?

So I want it to function as follow:

Click link - `$("div").slideDown();`

Exit `$("div")` - `$("div").slideUp();`

Exit `$("div")` into `$("div-2")` don't `$("div").slideUp();`

Exit `$("div-2")` back into `$("div")` don't `$("div").slideUp();`

Exit `$("div-2")` - `$("div").slideUp();`

Heres the javascript with jQuery I've got so far:

```
$('.dropdown-link > a').click(function() {
  var link = this;
  if ($(".navigation-dropdown").is(':hidden')) {
    $(".navigation-dropdown").slideDown(1000, 'swing', function() {
      switcher(link, $('#' + $(link).attr('data-panel-id')));
    });
  } else {
    switcher(this, $('#' + $(this).attr('data-panel-id')))
 };
  $(".navigation-dropdown").mouseleave(function(event) {
    $(".navigation-dropdown").slideUp(1000, 'swing');
    $(".active-item").removeClass('active-item');
  });
});

function switcher(link, panel) {
  $(".panel").stop().hide();
  $(".active-item").removeClass('active-item');
  $(panel).fadeIn(200);
  $(link).parent().addClass('active-item');
};
```

Heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/OGZStudios/qdp42cph/9/

Here's the result of what I've got so far for better concept: http://woodlandbible.tk

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
function switcher(link,panel){
    $(".panel").fadeOut(function() {
        $(".active-item").removeClass('active-item');
        $(panel).fadeIn(200);
        $(link).parent().addClass('active-item');
    });

};
```

This should fade out any open panels, and when they are gone, fade in the new panel and modify your links. The problem is manually checking for visibility when jQuery is in the process of fading stuff in and out. It can do it all for you!

Regarding shorter code: You need a way to tie each link to each panel. Right now those connections are hard coded in the script, but suppose you gave the link a `data-panel-id` attribute with the id of the corresponding panel, all your `.click` handlers reduce to:

```
$('.panel').click(function(){
     switcher(this,$('#' + $(this).attr('data-panel-id')))
});
```

EDIT: Use `$(".panel").stop()` to end all ongoing animations. The following worked for me in JSFiddle:

```
function switcher(link,panel){
    $(".panel").stop().hide();
     $(".active-item").removeClass('active-item');
     $(panel).fadeIn(200);
     $(link).parent().addClass('active-item');

};
```

Comment: No, I was there earlier and it just spawns a continuous series of fadeIns and fadeOuts and you end up with a bunch of the different panels stacked up with everything bouncing around all over the place. Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah that's a better way of doing it, at least we're not iterating through the panels anymore looking for :visible. But it still takes two clicks before it does anything. Once you go through the two clicks it works as you think it would, but you have to click a link or combination of links twice. Upvote for all the help with cleaning up the code and helping me figure out a more efficient way to hide the exposed panel though! Your method also kills the problem with clicking the links too fast!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the double click issue is because i'm trying to switch panels before the dropdown is actually  :visible yet

Comment: I got the double click issue figured out with the code above, as seen on the fiddle. I still can't figure out how to keep the dropdown open when leaving the dropdown back to the navigation menu. I've updated the jQuery code above as well as the fiddle to apply this fix